# PostgreSQL errors and big database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, windows-server

Let's start from point that I have been introduced to PostgreSQL only 
a couple days ago after I received alert from monitoring system that one of local discs on one of VMs if almost full.

After checking I found that there is BNA (Broadcom switch configuration and logs storage) software running on that machine and the problem is a huge PosgreSQL database. Almost 100GB.

Next point is that I only have experience with Redis and MySQL. So I was forced to spend a lot of time trying to learn how Vacuum garbage collector works but I can't understand that on practice. I need your help.

Here are the VM and software specifications:
ESXi hypervisor,
12Gb RAM,
E2660 2.2GHz 4 cores,
Windows server 2012,
PostgreSQL 9.5.4.

Also I have to admit that it's a service that is configured in a strange way and controlled by BNA.
Service start string:

```
C:\Program Files\Network Advisor IP 14.2.11\db\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -N "dcm-database" -D "C:\Program Files\Network Advisor IP 14.2.11\data\databases" -w -t 180
```

So my questions are:
1) How can I check that the database is optimised by vacuum? And that it's real database size without garbage.

String in config is commented:
`#autovacuum = on`
but looks like it's working:

```
dcmdb=# select name, setting from pg_settings where name = 'autovacuum' ;

    name    | setting
------------+---------
 autovacuum | on
(1 row)
```

DB size:

```
dcmdb=# SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database()));
pg_size_pretty---------------- 96 GB (1 row)

dcmdb=#SELECT 
dcmdb=#    schemaname
dcmdb=#    ,relname
dcmdb=#    ,n_live_tup
dcmdb=#    ,n_dead_tup
dcmdb=#    ,last_autovacuum
dcmdb=#FROM pg_stat_all_tables 
dcmdb=#ORDER BY n_dead_tup
dcmdb=#    /(n_live_tup
dcmdb=#      * current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor')::float8
dcmdb=#     + current_setting('autovacuum_vacuum_threshold')::float8)
dcmdb=#     DESC;


     schemaname     |                  relname                  | n_live_tup | n
_dead_tup |        last_autovacuum
--------------------+-------------------------------------------+------------+--
----------+-------------------------------
 dcm                | vip_server                                |        590 |
     1093 | 2020-04-15 09:13:52.295072-04
 dcm                | gbit_ethernet_interface                   |       1384 |
     1203 | 2020-04-15 10:37:53.688356-04
 dcm                | scenario_device_binding                   |     159803 |
    29750 | 2020-03-15 03:02:44.913199-04
 dcm                | device_config_entry                       |     161459 |
    30000 | 2020-03-15 03:03:48.066086-04
 pg_catalog         | pg_depend                                 |   15011894 |
  2706092 | 2020-01-25 22:31:52.540672-05
 pg_catalog         | pg_type                                   |    2011906 |
   362762 | 2020-03-27 19:57:43.912656-04
 dcm                | event_description                         |      19838 |
     4461 | 2020-04-14 00:00:42.83755-04
 dcm                | health_target_status                      |        680 |
     1020 | 2020-03-31 08:01:06.114402-04
 dcm                | scenario                                  |     155993 |
    28158 | 2020-03-16 03:04:56.939647-04
 dcm                | scenario_binding                          |     159887 |
    28788 | 2020-03-16 03:03:57.517215-04
 dcm                | qrtz_fired_triggers                       |          0 |
      841 |
 pg_toast           | pg_toast_2619                             |         70 |
      844 | 2020-03-22 04:24:02.66603-04
 dcm                | l2_neighbor                               |        197 |
      859 | 2020-04-14 17:32:06.27739-04
 pg_catalog         | pg_attribute                              |   18956877 |
  3020858 | 2020-03-20 03:09:11.19122-04
 dcm                | vlan                                      |        779 |
      908 | 2020-04-14 16:07:01.081089-04
 dcm                | device_config                             |     161463 |
    25877 | 2020-03-19 03:02:13.73173-04
 pg_catalog         | pg_constraint                             |    1004927 |
   155380 | 2019-12-28 14:00:51.903803-05
 dcm                | cfg_backup_detail                         |     155833 |
    24212 | 2020-04-02 03:05:30.918179-04
 dcm                | collection_end_timestamp                  |        163 |
      777 | 2020-04-07 03:21:32.891011-04
 pg_catalog         | pg_index                                  |    1004293 |
   146176 | 2020-01-09 21:08:54.369106-05
 dcm                | stp_port                                  |        200 |
      688 | 2020-04-09 09:42:44.426569-04
 pg_catalog         | pg_statistic                              |    1542281 |
   202473 | 2019-12-10 18:48:55.90094-05
 dcm                | cfg_backup_archive                        |        250 |
      670 |
 dcm                | last_config_update_time                   |        188 |
      643 | 2020-01-05 18:42:42.510495-05
 dcm                | port_vlan                                 |        732 |
      706 | 2020-02-08 16:34:12.597755-05
 dcm                | interface                                 |       1577 |
      807 | 2020-04-15 10:50:58.137137-04
 dcm                | device                                    |         30 |
      602 |
 dcm                | virtual_interface                         |        129 |
      594 |
 dcm                | switch_port                               |        464 |
      569 |
 dcm                | qrtz_triggers                             |          1 |
      515 | 2020-01-02 16:53:19.577717-05
 dcm                | cee_port                                  |        432 |
      507 |
 dcm                | user_preference                           |         86 |
      443 |
 dcm                | gige_port                                 |        432 |
      457 |
 pg_toast           | pg_toast_21093                            |         26 |
      396 | 2020-04-14 17:07:05.304957-04
 dcm                | event                                     |      60107 |
     4245 | 2020-04-15 00:01:11.145676-04
 dcm                | ethernet_interface                        |         33 |
      309 |
 dcm                | health_status                             |         50 |
      299 | 2020-02-21 08:01:46.308445-05
 dcm                | table_sequence                            |        257 |
      296 |
 pg_toast           | pg_toast_22208                            |        862 |
      326 | 2020-04-15 04:14:10.540705-04
 pg_catalog         | pg_class                                  |    1986275 |
-- More  --
```

2) How do I fix this error? If I properly understood, the situation is that the client is trying to send/get data via IPv6. Right?

```
SQL statement "SELECT dblink_connect('dblink_trans',dblink_str)"
    PL/pgSQL function purge_aged_tables(text,integer,text,text,integer) line 50 at PERFORM 08001
2020-04-15 10:30:07.813 EDT {[unknown]} [3820:1-1] LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=27450
2020-04-15 10:30:07.814 EDT {[unknown]} [3820:2-1] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dcmadmin"
2020-04-15 10:30:07.814 EDT {[unknown]} [3820:3-1] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 117: "host    all             all                 ::0/0                   md5   "
2020-04-15 10:30:07.815 EDT {TimeSeriesDataAging_Timer} [4328:4-1] WARNING:  Error while executing function purge_aged_tables : could not establish connection FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dcmadmin"
```

There are 2 DB users `dcmuser` and `dcmadmin` according to this config:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5  
host    all             dcmuser             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

The first one can connect from everywhere and dcmadmin only from localhost.

PS: Checked logs after attempts to login:
Suitable password:

```
psql "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dcmdb user=dcmadmin password=suitablepass"
```

```
2020-04-16 17:48:18.149 EDT {[unknown]} [3024:1-1] LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=41061
2020-04-16 17:48:18.151 EDT {[unknown]} [3024:2-1] LOG:  connection authorized: user=dcmadmin database=dcmdb
2020-04-16 17:53:38.728 EDT {pg_dump} [4140:7-1] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:57.233 user=dcmadmin database=dcmdb host=::1 port=41105
```

Suitable password (specifying IP):

```
psql "host=10.31.6.52 port=5432 dbname=dcmdb user=dcmadmin password=suitablepass"
```

```
2020-04-16 17:54:30.351 EDT {[unknown]} [1560:1-1] LOG:  connection received: host=10.31.6.52 port=41109
2020-04-16 17:54:30.353 EDT {[unknown]} [1560:2-1] LOG:  connection authorized: user=dcmadmin database=dcmdb
2020-04-16 17:55:38.648 EDT {psql} [1560:3-1] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:01:08.297 user=dcmadmin database=dcmdb host=10.31.6.52 port=41109
```

Comment: "*password authentication failed for user "dcmadmin"*" - can be fixed by providing the correct password.

Comment: This installation (I mean BNA) has hard-codded credentials for database and it's impossible to change user\password using BNA software. Looks like it's IPv6 or access configuration pg_hba.conf issues.

Comment: No, if it's a problem with `pg_hba.conf` there would be a different error message. This clearly shows that the wrong password was sent. What does `show password_encryption;` give you? (when connected as the superuser)

Comment: dcmdb=# show password_encryption;
 password_encryption
---------------------
 on
(1 row)

Comment: You are totally right about wrong password and according logs it's trying to use IPv6.
(host=::1)